# How to handle one to many relation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

How do I correctly echo a one to many query result?

With a one table query result I would just echo each row after fetching it, for example:

```
+---+------+
|ID | title|
|1  | a    |
|2  | b    |
|3  | c    |
+---+------+

$smtp->bind_result($ID, $title);
while($smtp->fetch()) {
    \\echo here                        
}
```

But after using a query with a natural join (example below), I have no idea how to echo it in PHP as: 
"3 - c - Action, Fantasy, Military"

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | title | genre    |
|  3 |   c   | Action   |
|  3 |   c   | Fantasy  |
|  3 |   c   | Military |
+----+-------+----------+
```

EDIT:

Let me rephrase the question. When using a one to many relationship, how do I properly showcase the results from the "many" table?

This is the code I use at the moment.

```
//connect to database with self made db class object.
$db = new db();
$db = $db->connect();

$smtp = $db->prepare('select ID, title, description, genre from movie NATURAL JOIN movie_genres WHERE date >= ? AND date < ?');
$smtp->bind_param('ss', $seasonStart, $seasonEnd); //variables defined based on current date.
$smtp->execute();
$smtp->bind_result($ID, $title,$description, $genre));
while($smtp->fetch()) {
    echo '
    <div class="upcoming">
        <div id="upcomingPoster" style="background-image: url(images/' . $ID . '.jpeg)">
            <div>
                <a href="">' . $title . '</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="upcomingInfo">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p class="upcomingInfoDescription">' . $description .'</p>
            <div></div>
            <p>' . $genre . '</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Now when using this, my code basically loops for every row. But I am trying to put all of the genres next to each other, before it loops to the next movie.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: And the query you're using too, while you're at it, please.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for array_merge() http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Usually its not PHP that has to handle it, you use a `JOIN` in your SQL query and MySQL provides you with a promptly associated result. Thats the whole point of using a DBMS, its so you don't have to code that stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bind_result($ID, $title, $genre);
$movies = array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($movies[$ID])){
        $movies[$ID] = array('title'=>$title, 'genres'=>array());
    }
    $movies[$ID]['genres'][] = $genre;
}
foreach ($movies as $ID=>$movie){
    echo $ID . ' - ' . $movie['title'] . ' - ';
    $first = true;
    foreach ($movie['genres'] as $genre){
        if (!first) echo ', ';
        $first = false;
        echo $genre;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do and if that what I understand is wanted you wanted to ask.

I think you are using PHP-PDO so it is necessary to store the result of fetch on the sql-statement to another variable. This could look like this:

```
$smtp->bind_result($ID, $title);
while($result = $smtp->fetch()) {
  var_dump($result);
}
```

So now you should see the data of the fetched row.